# Too many connections with apache commons-vfs2

Tags: java, apache, sftp, apache-commons, apache-commons-vfs

I have an application that needs to download files from sftp.
I'm currently using apache commons-vfs2

I have a scheduler that runs every 1 minute.
 1. Get the list of files that's on remote (open connection, get the list, then close connection)
 2. Download the files from step 1 (open connection, download each files, then close connection)

How can I keep the connections to minimum? 
Is there a way to limit how many connections I have with commons-vfs2?

Here is my code

```
private List<FileObject> getRemoteFilesList() throws FileSystemException {
        FileObject[] remoteFiles;
        try {
            manager.init();
            final @Cleanup FileObject remoteDirectoryObject = manager.resolveFile(uri, fileSystemOptions);
            remoteFiles = remoteDirectoryObject.getChildren();

        } finally {
            manager.freeUnusedResources();
            manager.close();
        }
        return Arrays.stream(remoteFiles)
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

private List<File> downloadRemoteFiles(final List<FileObject> remoteFiles) {
        if(remoteFiles.isEmpty()) {
            return Collections.emptyList();
        }

        final List<File> myCollection = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            manager.init();

            for (final FileObject myfile : remoteFiles) {
                final File localFile = downloadFile(myfile);
                myCollection.add(localFile);
                myfile.delete();
            }
        } catch (final IOException exception) {
            log.warn("Unable to download because ", exception);
        } finally {
            manager.freeUnusedResources();
            manager.close();
        }
        return myCollection;
    }
```

Comment: I would not init and close a shared Filesystem manager. especially not the default one. If you reuse a single manager it will also reuse open connections. Also make sure your downloadFile() method actual closes the stream.

Answer (score 2):

The apache commons wiki for VFS (https://wiki.apache.org/commons/VfsFaq) says to use the following when closing an SFTP connection in certain circumstances:

```
((DefaultFileSystemManager) fsManager).close();
```

This forces the `close` method on the `DefaultFileSystemManager` to be called, rather than the `close` method on the `FileSystemManager` class.

It may not be your issue, but it's something that may be related.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this alternative method to clean up any temporary files and close all providers.

```
FileObject src = null;

/**
 * Release system resources, close connection to the filesystem. 
 */
public void release() {
    FileSystem fs = null;

    this.src.close(); // Seems to still work even if this line is omitted
    fs = this.src.getFileSystem(); // This works even after the src is closed.
    this.fsManager.closeFileSystem(fs);
}
```

More details can be found on: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/COMMONS/SimpleSftpFileDownload